# How to remove white space between a leading left arrow & trailing text?

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have a string that I need to parse to an XElement for further processing (I don't have control over the input string, and this is a simplified version of the actual XML, but demonstrates the problem adequately):

```
string inputXML = @"
    <
    blahblahblahblahblah>";
```

I'm trying to remove the carriage returns & white space immediately after the opening left arrow (XElement won't parse it with leading spaces after the opening left arrow).  Here's what I've tried:

```
//tried making new strings instead of reusing the existing one,
//didn't make any difference
string test = inputXML.Replace("\r\n",""); 
string test2 = test.Replace(@"^<\s+", "<");
Console.WriteLine(test2);
```

This results in a string that looks like this:

```
<        blahblahblahblahblah>
```

Instead of this:

```
<blahblahblahblahblah>
```

Other than the above, I have also tried:

```
inputXML.Replace(@"<[ ]+", "<");  //doesn't work
inputXML.Replace(@"< +", "<");  //doesn't work
inputXML.Replace(@"<\040+", "<");  //doesn't work
inputXML.Replace(@"<        ", "<"); //works!, but not very useful and I don't
//understand why I need twice as many spaces as the actual number?  Since I don't
//control the input, this isn't a solution, it only happens to work for this one.
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something stupid.  All of these regex expressions work in **[www.rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com)** which I realize is for Ruby, but it's handy for testing.

I'm also not married to doing this with a regex, so if you've got another suggestion, I'm all ears.

I don't think it's germane, but I'm testing this in LINQPad.

Comment: Can't you just [Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim(v=vs.110).aspx) the extra white space?

Comment: I thoroughly recommend Rad Software Regular Expression Designer for cooking up .Net regular expressions. It looks like Rad Software is no more, but the tool is still available elsewhere.

Comment: @Brian How would trim work in this scenario? Trim only removes leading and trailing characters, not anything in the middle of a string.

Comment: Found a copy...: http://freedownloadshare.com/archive/dl.php?id=xSCdQhA3&dir=file&name=Rad.RegexDesigner.Setup.1.4.exe  I checked and it's byte-for-byte identical to the installer I downloaded from Rad Software and have used for years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. `string.Replace` doesn't work with regular expressions. Use [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.
2. The `^` anchor in the string means the `<` must appear at the start of the string. If you're just trying to remove the spaces after the first `<`, remove the anchor.

Try this:

```
string test = inputXML.Replace("\r\n",""); 
string test2 = Regex.Replace(test, @"<\s*", "<");
Console.WriteLine(test2); // "    <blahblahblahblahblah>"
```

Or if you'd also like to remove any whitespace before the `<`, use this:

```
string test = inputXML.Replace("\r\n",""); 
string test2 = Regex.Replace(test, @"\s*<\s*", "<");
Console.WriteLine(test2); // "<blahblahblahblahblah>"
```

Comment: I didn't realize that .Replace didn't work with regex, thanks for explaining that to me.  It's much simpler when you use the right tools.  Your changes to use Regex.Replace() work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Given the arbitrary content of XML, it's probably only safe to remove whitespace that lies within tags. So:

```
string inputXML = @"
<
blahblahblahblahblah>";
string pattern = @"(?<=\<)\s+"; //match one or more whitespace following a <
var cleaned = Regex.Replace(inputXML,
                            pattern, 
                            string.Empty,
                            RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

Comment: As I explained to AaronS above, I should have included one of the <Notes> nodes in my example.  I have to preserve the user typed notes if they exist, so I can't remove all spaces, I have to be very precise in those I do remove.  I suspect your version may well work (and I'll test it shortly) even with that caveat.  I just re-read your explanation, and this should work as well since it's only working inside tags.  Can you explain the regex please?  I don't understand what the question mark & equals signs do.